# Torch: Confusion on weights and optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, torch

If I want to convert the code snippet from Python to Torch, are these two equivalent?

```
class RNN:
  # ...
  def step(self, x):
    # update the hidden state
    self.h = np.tanh(np.dot(self.W_hh, self.h) + np.dot(self.W_xh, x))
    # compute the output vector
    y = np.dot(self.W_hy, self.h)
    return y
```

And code for Torch:

```
RNN = {}
function RNN.step(x, prev_h)
  -- give them weights and bias
  local h2h = nn.Linear( rnnsize, rnnsize )(prev_h)
  local i2h = nn.Linear( insize, rnnsize )(x)
  -- calculate next hidden state
  local next_h = nn.Tanh()( nn.CAddTable(){ h2h, i2h } )
  return next_h
end
```

, where `nn.Linear` gives hidden states and input a weighted linear transformation. But where are the weight matrices kept for later's optimization? Similar use of Linear() function can be found in [LSTM's code](https://github.com/wojzaremba/lstm/blob/master/main.lua#L65) on GitHub:

```
local function lstm(x, prev_c, prev_h)
  -- Calculate all four gates in one go
  local i2h = nn.Linear(params.rnn_size, 4*params.rnn_size)(x)
  local h2h = nn.Linear(params.rnn_size, 4*params.rnn_size)(prev_h)
  local gates = nn.CAddTable()({i2h, h2h})

  -- gates calculations
  -- ...

  local next_c           = nn.CAddTable()({
  nn.CMulTable()({forget_gate, prev_c}),
  nn.CMulTable()({in_gate,     in_transform})
  })
  local next_h           = nn.CMulTable()({out_gate, nn.Tanh()(next_c)})

  return next_c, next_h
end
```

It seemed each time input (`x`, `prev_c`, `prev_h`) pushed through the LSTM unit, the weights inside are generated once again. So how could this model be optimized and weights decay during training? And yet another question about `nn.optim` is that there's a `f` [passed to the optimization functions](https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/2_supervised/4_train.lua#L145), which outputs `f(x)` and `df / dx`. What does this `f` mean? If itself represents the error estimation (seemed to have done all necessary calculations), what is the use of an `optim.sgd` or `optim.adadelta` function?